# ModRewrite remove /index.php/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got old urls and want to remove the /index.php/ via .htaccess:

So **old url** is:

```
  www.mysite.com/index.php/onesite.html
```

**rewrite** in .htaccess into

```
 www.mysite.com/onesite.html
```

How can I do that?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/.*)?$ $1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and what URL did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to your htaccess will allow this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ www.mysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Changing `302` to `301` when you are sure the redirect is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*?)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you site is in subfolder then

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```